# Combining two promises

Tags: javascript, push-notification, promise, service-worker

I am really new to JavaScript and promises and to be honest I don't fully understand how promises work so I need some help.

I am using Google Cloud Messaging to push notifications from my site to my users. When users receive a notification and clicks on it, it opens a URL stored in a IndexedDB.

```
importScripts('IndexDBWrapper.js');
var KEY_VALUE_STORE_NAME = 'key-value-store', idb;

function getIdb() {
  if (!idb) {
    idb = new IndexDBWrapper(KEY_VALUE_STORE_NAME, 1, function (db) {
      db.createObjectStore(KEY_VALUE_STORE_NAME);
    });
  }
  return idb;
}

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  console.log('On notification click: ', event);
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(getIdb().get(KEY_VALUE_STORE_NAME, event.notification.tag).then(function (url) {
    var redirectUrl = '/';
    if (url) redirectUrl = url;
      return clients.openWindow(redirectUrl);
  }));
});
```

So in the code above, I know that the getIdb()...then() is a promise, but is the event.waitUntil also a promise?

The problem with the above code is that it opens a instance of Chrome every time the notification is clicked and I would prefer that it would utilize an existing instance if available. The following does just that:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {  
  console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);  
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({  
      type: "window"  
    })
    .then(function(clientList) {  
      for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {  
        var client = clientList[i];  
        if (client.url == '/' && 'focus' in client)  
          return client.focus();  
      }  
      if (clients.openWindow) {
        return clients.openWindow('/');  
      }
    })
  );
});
```

However, now I have two promises, getIdb and clients.matchAll and I really have no idea how to combine the two promises and the two sets of code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

For reference, here is IndexDBWrapper.js:

```
'use strict';

function promisifyRequest(obj) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    function onsuccess(event) {
      resolve(obj.result);
      unlisten();
    }
    function onerror(event) {
      reject(obj.error);
      unlisten();
    }
    function unlisten() {
      obj.removeEventListener('complete', onsuccess);
      obj.removeEventListener('success', onsuccess);
      obj.removeEventListener('error', onerror);
      obj.removeEventListener('abort', onerror);
    }
    obj.addEventListener('complete', onsuccess);
    obj.addEventListener('success', onsuccess);
    obj.addEventListener('error', onerror);
    obj.addEventListener('abort', onerror);
  });
}

function IndexDBWrapper(name, version, upgradeCallback) {
  var request = indexedDB.open(name, version);
  this.ready = promisifyRequest(request);
  request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    upgradeCallback(request.result, event.oldVersion);
  };
}

IndexDBWrapper.supported = 'indexedDB' in self;

var IndexDBWrapperProto = IndexDBWrapper.prototype;

IndexDBWrapperProto.transaction = function(stores, modeOrCallback, callback) {
  return this.ready.then(function(db) {
    var mode = 'readonly';

    if (modeOrCallback.apply) {
      callback = modeOrCallback;
    }
    else if (modeOrCallback) {
      mode = modeOrCallback;
    }

    var tx = db.transaction(stores, mode);
    var val = callback(tx, db);
    var promise = promisifyRequest(tx);
    var readPromise;

    if (!val) {
      return promise;
    }

    if (val[0] && 'result' in val[0]) {
      readPromise = Promise.all(val.map(promisifyRequest));
    }
    else {
      readPromise = promisifyRequest(val);
    }

    return promise.then(function() {
      return readPromise;
    });
  });
};

IndexDBWrapperProto.get = function(store, key) {
  return this.transaction(store, function(tx) {
    return tx.objectStore(store).get(key);
  });
};

IndexDBWrapperProto.put = function(store, key, value) {
  return this.transaction(store, 'readwrite', function(tx) {
    tx.objectStore(store).put(value, key);
  });
};

IndexDBWrapperProto.delete = function(store, key) {
  return this.transaction(store, 'readwrite', function(tx) {
    tx.objectStore(store).delete(key);
  });
};
```

Comment: It sounds like [`event.waitUntil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil) is a method that *takes* a promise.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the tip. Knowing the actual names of these things will help me greatly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`event.waitUntil()` takes a promise - this allows the browser to keep your worker alive until you've finished what you want to do (i.e. until the promise that you gave to `event.waitUntil()` has resolved).

As the other answer suggests, you can use `Promise.all()` within `event.waitUntil`. `Promise.all()` takes an array of promises and returns a promise, so you can call `then` on it. Your handling function will get an array of promise results when all of the promises you've provided to `Promise.all` have resolved. Your code will then look something like this (I haven't actually tested this, but it should be close):

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(Promise.all([
      getIdb().get(KEY_VALUE_STORE_NAME, event.notification.tag),
      clients.matchAll({ type: "window" })
    ]).then(function (resultArray) {
    var url = resultArray[0] || "/";
    var clientList = resultArray[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
      var client = clientList[i];
      if (client.url == '/' && 'focus' in client)
        return client.focus();
    }
    if (clients.openWindow) {
      return clients.openWindow(url);
    }
  }));
});
```

Comment: I had looked into Promise.all(), but I had my .then() in the array of promises instead of at. Your code does the trick. I'm slowly starting to understand promises. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Personally I found [the chapter on promises](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20&%20performance/ch3.md) in *You Don't Know JS: Async and Performance* pretty helpful, especially after reading it twice!

Comment: Now I just have to wait for the `client.navigate(url)` method to be implemented. When it does get implemented, what's the best way to return both `client.navigate(url)`and `client.focus()`?

Comment: ... also that's a great resource!

Comment: They both return promises, so I guess you could call them both inside Promise.all again, or chain one off the other, but I'm not sure offhand.

Comment: Here's another good resource with some Promise-gotchas: http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Answer (score 30):

One way to deal with multiple promises is with `Promise.all`

```
Promise.all([promise0, promise1, promise2]).then(function(valArray) {
    // valArray[0] is result of promise0
    // valArray[1] is result of promise1
    // valArray[2] is result of promise2
});
```

read about promise.all - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Notice that `Promise.all` does take an iterable (e.g. an array), but not multiple arguments

Comment: yeah, thatnks for that, I originally had the promise and the then function with multiple arguments (been a while since I've used it) and fixed one but not the other

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve two promises at the same time using the Promise.all() in javascript

follow : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

for example:

1.Create a Promise that resolve with number 10 after 3 seconds
2.Create another Promise that resolve with number 20 after 5 seconds

So, how can we logout to sum of 30 of these two resolved values, once after both promises are fulfilled:

```
const myPromise1=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
    resolve(10)
  },3000)
})


myPromise1.then((data)=>{
  console.log(data)
})


const myPromise2=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
    resolve(20)
  },5000)
})


myPromise2.then((da)=>{
  console.log(da)
})


Promise.all([myPromise1,myPromise2]).then((values)=>{
  console.log(values[0]+values[1])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I am very late to the party but,

I think you can use this very light, vanilla JS library that does things for you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-promise-all

Here is the small code sample for it.

```
var { EasyPromiseAll } = require('easy-promise-all');

EasyPromiseAll({
    resultFromPromise1: Promise.resolve('first'),
    resultFromPromise2: Promise.reject('second'),
  }).then((results) => {
    const { resultFromPromise1, resultFromPromise2 } = results;
    console.log(resultFromPromise1, resultFromPromise2);
  });
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25137462)

Comment: @ivaigult You are right. I have added the snippet for the betterment.

Comment: Why use an extra dependency for such a thing when `Promise.all` fits the bill?

Comment: It is overhead when you have two different type of responses in an array (result of Promise.all()), and need to figure which indexes would carry result1 & result2 (we can' rely on sequence only). That's why.